# How do I get my file to be saved as JSON after writing a JSON file into AWS S3 bucket

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to write a JSON file into my AWS S3 bucket. However, I do not get a JSON file after it has been uploaded.

I get my data from a website using a request.get() and format it into a JSON file which I then run the following script to upload it to me S3 bucket.

```
r = requests.get(url=id_url, params=params)
data = r.json()

s3_client.put_object(
    Body=json.dumps(data, indent=3),
    Bucket='bucket-name',
    Key=fileName
)
```

However, I am not sure what the type of file is but it is supposed to be saved as a JSON file.

[Screenshot of my S3 bucket having no file type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1DXZ.png)

[Screenshot of my download folder, showing unable to identify the file type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nuEc.png)

When I open the file by selecting Pycharm, it is just a dictionary with key and values

Comment: Your question is unclear and lacks details. What exactly is your json data? Do you have any examples for before and after uploading to S3?

Comment: What do you get when you download it if not JSON?  "dictionary with key and values" is a description of a file containing JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I simply added ".JSON" to the filename and it has solved the file formatting issue. Dont know why I didnt think of this earlier.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you shouldn't rely of file extensions to specify the content type. The [`put_object`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) method supports specifying `ContentType`. This means that you can use any file name you like, without needing to specify `.json`.

e.g.

```py
s3_client.put_object(
    Body=json.dumps(data, indent=3),
    Bucket='bucket-name',
    Key=fileName,
    ContentType='application/json'
)
```